# Programmatically open credential store (Android)

Tags: android, wifi, launcher

We have a AOSP device that does not have a keyboard or touch (wearable). We can attach a keyboard via Bluetooth but that is only for development purposes.

Furthermore, we use Enterprise Wifi (WPA2-Enterprise using TLS and MSCHAPv2) at our shop that uses a corporate certificate + private certificate. 
Everything works but there is a very annoying problem. After every reboot, somebody has to type in the password for the credential store and then again confirm the "PIN".

Is there any programmatic way to "open" the credential store & "PIN" at startup? Without doing so, it is not possible to connect to the WiFi.

We are willing to create a custom launcher or ROM if needed.

Android Version: 4.0.4

Comment: reason to open if you still won't be able to enter something?

Comment: @gio I am asking how I can enable Android to use the certificate without user interaction. If "opening" the credential store is not the right wording, let me know.